# Execute the setInterval function without a delay the first time

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there any way to show without delay for the first time?

This is so I can get the value without delay for the first time and then refresh the value in the background.

```html
<script>
function ajax() 
{ 
    var request = null; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 
    if(request) 
    { 
    request.open("GET", "troops.php"); 
    request.onreadystatechange = function () 
    { 
        
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = request.responseText; 
    

    } 
    } 
    request.send(null); 
}
setInterval("ajax()",250)
</script>

<div id="main">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just call `ajax` manually the first time (before `setInterval`)

also XMLHttpRequest is kind of legacy, `fetch` is the new thing

```html
<div id="main"></div>

<script>
  const main = document.getElementById('main')
  const asText = r => r.text()
  const render = t => main.innerHTML = t

  function ajax() { 
    fetch('https://httpbin.org/get').then(asText).then(render)
  }

  ajax()
  setInterval(ajax, 2000)
</script>
```